# touchend event firing at a delay while using trackpad or touchscreen

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

The `touchend` event takes a while to fire while I'm using the trackpad or a touchscreen for swiping. The delay does not happen while I'm using the mouse to simulate touch. It's messing up a touch slider I have created.

I have created a bare page which also shows the issue. Please check on Chrome mobile simulator: https://codepen.io/shakil_ahmed/full/BadWQvN

Any workarounds for this?

Comment: I have checked the code buddy and it is working as it is supposed to.
The touch end event should fire when you lift your finger and should not fire while you are holding your finger on the phone. Can you elaborate more about what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: Better Workaround: If you're trying to build a touch-friendly slider, may I suggest just making a scrollable area using `overflow: auto` and `scroll-snap` in CSS. It gives you much nicer sliders for touch screens *and* trackpads with just a little bit of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Could your issue be related to this? https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away

If so it looks like adding the CSS `touch-action: manipulation;` to `html` (or `body`) could fix your issue.

Comment: The touch-delay should only affect click events and not touch events, so I don't think it's that.